# Different signatures in operator overrides

Tags: c++, vector

I'm looking at some basic vector library, the class has two signatures for the `operator*`, but I can't get my head around the differences between the two.

```
vec4 vec4::operator*(float c) const {
    return vec4(data[0] * c, data[1] * c, data[2] * c, data[3] * c);
};

vec4 operator*(float c, const vec4 &v) {
    return vec4(c * v[0], c * v[1], c * v[2], c * v[3]);
};
```

- How do both look when used ?
- Is there a reason why one uses `vec4::operator` and the other just `operator*` ?

Thank you!

Comment: You have included code out of context - (1) is a member function; (2) is a standalone function.  Note that (1) can do `vec4 * c` but needs (2) to do `c * vec4`  - (2) should really call (1) to make this clear.

Comment: `float * vec4` requires free function whereas `vec4 * float` might be free function or member function (for symmetry, I would use free functions for both).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one is a member function. That means you have a declaration inside a class, like so:

```
class vec4 {
  public:
    vec4 operator*(float c) const;
};
```

and it's definition outside the class:

```
vec4 vec4::operator*(float c) const {
    return vec4(data[0] * c, data[1] * c, data[2] * c, data[3] * c);
};
```

It takes only one argument - the right hand side of the operation.
The left hand side has to be of type `vec4` (because it's a member of `vec4`)

This operator will handle expressions like:

```
vec4 v;
v = v * 4.f;
```

That's the same as this:

```
vec4 v;
v = v.operator*(4.f);
```

---

The second overload is a non-member function and thus needs two parameters.

```
vec4 operator*(float c, const vec4 &v) {
    return vec4(c * v[0], c * v[1], c * v[2], c * v[3]);
};
```

This operator can handle expression like this:

```
vec4 v;
v = 4.f * v;
```

That's equivalent to:

```
vec4 v;
v = operator*(4.f, v);
```

Answer (score -1):

As you can see at the end of the signature, one has the attribute `const` and the other doesn't. This means that the pointer to the class where these methods come from will be constant in one of the method so its members won't be able to change value.

Comment: (2) is a non-member function so can't be `const`

Comment: The first is a member function; the `const` says that it can be called with a `const` object. The second is a non-member function; the `const` in `const vec4 &v` says that it can be called with a `const` object. Basically, they do the same thing, but with the arguments reversed.